# Toastr Not working when Routing to different page

Tags: angular, navigation, router, toastr

This is the code in my delete function that calls for the service. The succes part in the subscribe is not working properly, in the sense that the toastr doesn't appear on the new page. But it would appear on the page before (navigating to another page makes it dissappear).

```
this._meetupService.deleteMeetup(id).subscribe(
                       () => {this._router.navigate(['/meetups']),
                        this.toastr.success('Successfully Deleted!');},
                        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to set the route for the ViewContainerRef inside the main component of your app.

You can do this by setting it within the constructor.

```
      constructor( public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }
```

P.S - Don't forget to import the ViewContainerRef from '@angular/core'